# AWS Cloudformation EC2: reexecute Init

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

We use `AWS::CloudFormation::Init:`  to write configs and do some commands at startup time. This works okay for us.

But if we update that part (add a command, or edit a file) this isn't executed again when we update the stack. Only when we delete and recreate the stack.

What is the recommended way to solve this? We have some commands which only need to be executed in the initial creation (init) but we also have some files/commands which we want to be read/executed after a stackupdate.